# How can I determine what % of git commits touch a file or directory?

Tags: git

I'm trying to use git log to look through the commit history and figure out, given a period of time, how many commits touched certain sub-folders of the codebase.

Maybe there is a tool out there that reports this sort of statistics. But I feel like this should be possible as a one-liner or short script of commands.

I'm on Windows, but a unix friendly script would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easy way to get the number of commits that touched a files is to just look at the log for that file.

```
git log --follow -- path/to/my/file
```

The `--follow` will follow renames, and the `--` is there in case the file path is ambiguous (and looks like a branch name or something).

You can count the results with:

```
git log --format=oneline --follow -- _exec.sh  | wc -l
```

The total number of commits is given by:

```
git rev-list HEAD | wc -l
```

These commands will look at the current branch (and its ancestors) only, you can look at stats for all branches by passing `--all` to both `rev-list` and `log`.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to use this idea to create this:

tested=`git log --all-match --author="author_name" --grep="PR [0-9]" -i --format=oneline --since="3 months ago" --follow -- path/to/directory | wc -l`

total=`git log --all-match --author="author_name" --grep="PR [0-9]" -i --format=oneline --since="3 months ago" HEAD | wc -l`

Which can be used to calculate the % of commits from a person that touched a folder.